# How to redirect to current url in java?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm using

```
<%=request.getRequestURL()%>
```

to redirect to current page but it has problem with addresses with some parameters like this:

```
http://xxx.com/yyy/x/search?mesg=welcome&initial=true&app=
```

and redirects to address without parameter which causes problems.

is there any solution to get whole of address?

Comment: you can pass all parameter which ones you needed .

Comment: what is your server side technology

Comment: Did you mean refresh the page? Because, why someone would want to go elsewhere if you are already where you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect url using below two methods.

**Using core jsp taglib**.( I prefers this one)

```
<c:redirect url="your url">   
     <c:param name="mesg" value ="${mesg}" />   
     <c:param name="initial" value ="${initial}" /> 
     <c:param name="app" value="${app}" />
<c:redirect>
```

**Using scriptlet**

```
<%
  String queryString =  request.getQueryString();
  if(queryString != null) {
    response.sendRedirect("http://xxx.com/yyy/x/search?" + queryString); 
  }
  else {
    response.sendRedirect("http://xxx.com/yyy/x/search"); 
  }
%>
```

[getQueryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29), returns query string of the request ,but if no request parameters are supplied/availible then it returns `null` so you need to handle that `null`.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation for [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) states, it does not include the query string. I can't see any methods on `HttpServletRequest` that does include this "directly", so you might have to construct this yourself, which shouldn't be too difficult. You can use the `getParameterMap()` method to get a map of all query parameters.

**Edit**

[`HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) was the method I was looking for. Thanks @AlpeshGediya. So by combining it with `getRequestURL`, you have what you want.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString()

Comment: Was looking for it, but couldn't find it. Early morning... Thanks @AlpeshGediya

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the previous answers and wrote this:

```
<c:set var="parameter" value="<%=request.getQueryString()%>"/>
<c:if test="${not empty parameter}">
    <c:set var="parameter" value="?${parameter}"/>
</c:if>
```

thanks everbody